# Running Kendo Grid into .Net Fiddle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

To reproduce an issue a user recently [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293330/kendo-grid-pagination-does-not-work) related to Kendo grid, I thought it might be possible for me to use .NET Fiddle for it. But I am not able to load Kendo references. In my application I add a reference to Kendo.Mvc.dll.

I am wondering is there a way I can add a reference in .NET fiddle. .NET fiddle supports Nuget package however Kendo MVC wrapper does not come in a package.

My fiddle is: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRAJfO

[image: Fiddle with error image]

Just found that Kendo has got a tutorial that let you create charts and play around with it: http://dojo.telerik.com/. But it does not allow you to write ASP.NET MVC style code like .NET Fiddle does.

FYI - I have added a support ticket with telerik for this. Support ID:922106

Will update as soon as I hear back from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reply I received from Telerik:

The Kendo UI MVC assembly cannot be publicly accessible, that's why there is no public NuGet package which you can use to reference this assembly in tools such as .NET Fiddle.

The Kendo UI Dojo can be used to create examples with the vanilla HTML/Javascript Kendo UI widgets. There is no way to create fiddles featuring the Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC wrappers. If you need to provide examples and code, please send projects as attachments.

Dojo is designed to be an HTML/JS playground and the code is executed client-side. We currently do not provide a playground, which is able to execute server-side code.